# ionic 2.1.14 MediaPlugin methods undefined

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-media-plugin

I can't seem to place method on property that has `MediaPlugin` import.
It tells me it is `undefined`.
I want to keep the file link in the class and execute `wavplay()` from my `home.html`.

Here is my code:

```
//ionic start blank --v2    
//home.ts

    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { MediaPlugin } from 'ionic-native';

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })

    export class HomePage {

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

      wavfile = new MediaPlugin('file:///android_asset/www/mp3/testwav.wav');

      wavplay() {
        this.wavfile.play(); // .play() undefined
      }
      mp3play() {
        new MediaPlugin('file:///android_asset/www/mp3/testmp3.mp3').play(); //But this works
      }
    }
```

Any solution? I'm testing my app on android 6.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the file name in the class, use a property like this

```
//ionic start blank --v2    
//home.ts

    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { MediaPlugin } from 'ionic-native';

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })

    export class HomePage {

      private wavfile: any;  // <- Declare the class property

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
        // Initialize the property
        this.wavfile = new MediaPlugin('file:///android_asset/www/mp3/testwav.wav');
      }

      public wavplay(): void {
        this.wavfile.play();  // <- use it
      }
    }
```